# SApui5 Insert HTML into XML VIew

Tags: sapui5

I have an XML View, XML page and i want to insert HTML code into the view like `<A href >` ect with special css class but inside of my view like between Form and table . It is possible?

Comment: Can you give us a little code please?!

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is possible to use `HTML` controls in `XML` views by adding required namespace as below.

```
xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
```

Also, have a look at this [demo](http://jsbin.com/muxuwu/1/edit?html,js,output) where `a`(*anchor*) tag is added inside `XML` view.